# How can I weight the creation date of an article in thinking sphinx?

Tags: ruby, thinking-sphinx

I am using thinking sphinx to search an article database and I want to weight in the creation date so newer articles show first but I don't want to use sort since it will show the newest articles regardless of the relevance of them.

Is there any way that I could weight in the creation date so it will tend to show me newer articles but will also consider other factors in the order?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to create your own sorting algorithm, mixing in both the weight and the creation timestamp. Perhaps it's best to have the timestamp as the core weight, as it's going to be the much larger value by default - and then boost the relevance score before adding it in?

```
Model.search :sort_mode => :expr, :order => 'created_at + (@weight * 1000)'
```

See the [Thinking Sphinx docs](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#sorting) for more detail on this - and the [Sphinx docs](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sorting-modes) cover the mathematical functions available, too.

Comment: I ended up doing something like that. Created a custom field in the index: `has "DATEDIFF(NOW(), products.created_at)", :as => :days_old, :type => :integer` and then `:order => '@weight * (1 + (1 / days_old))`

Comment: If you are on Sphinx v1 or v2, you could also try the time segment sorting, as Pat explains here: http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/searching/ts2.html#sorting

Comment: This can sometimes break if the weight is big and record recent.. it overflows so the total score is close to zero.. I used '@weight * 10 + created_at / 100' to achieve the same effect but without this kind of problems...